# JAVA: If an error is caught, is the code in the try block that apperes after the error executed when the error is handled?

Tags: java, error-handling, try-catch

```
1 try{
2    this line of code throws exceptions;
3    is this line of code ever executed?; 
4 catch(MadeUpException ex){1
5    something happens in response to the exception!;
6 }
```

Is the third line of code executed if the first line of code throws and exceptions and in handling the exception the program is not killed.

Comment: **No**. Line 3 will be skipped. You could have tried it yourself.

Comment: ^^^thats an easy test. Just write a class and execute it :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In section [11.3. Run-Time Handling of an Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.3) of the JAVA8 specification says:

> The control transfer that occurs when an exception is thrown causes
>   **abrupt completion of expressions (§15.6) and statements (§14.1) until
>   a catch clause is encountered that can handle the exception**; execution
>   then continues by executing the block of that catch clause. **The code
>   that caused the exception is never resumed**.

So, as others noticed before, line 3 is skipped. Notice also that if the thrown exception is not a *MadeUpException* then even line 5 will be skipped!.

Answer (score 1):

No. The try block is interrupted as soon as an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The code will not run unless you fix the error in your catch block and retry. It stops immediately like a break; statement if an exception is thrown.